# Formularios dudas

Tags: php, html

Me surge una duda a ver si alguien me la puede solucionar. Tengo dos ficheros, uno es el formulario y otro es el que debería mandar los datos del formulario a una base de datos. Los dos están bien estructurados (me han ayudado a hacerlos) y funcionan por separados, pero cuando desde el formulario le mando al fichero de base de datos no me graba nada. Sera una tontería pero no doy con el tema, y me estoy volviendo loco pues voy con retraso en la entrega del proyecto.

Aquí paso los códigos:

formulario.-

```
<?php

// En primer lugar obtenemos la conexión y la guardamos en $link

$link=new mysqli('javiersaceda.es','javiers1_javiersaceda','zafiros1960');
echo "entramos";
//Seleccionar la base de datos
$db=mysqli_select_db($link,"javiers1_proyecto");
 

if (isset($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['apellidos']) && !empty($_POST['apellidos']) && isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['direccion']) && !empty($_POST['direccion']) && isset($_POST['poblacion']) && !empty($_POST['poblacion']) && isset($_POST['provincia']) && !empty($_POST['provincia']) && isset($_POST['cp']) && !empty($_POST['cp']) && isset($_POST['movil']) && !empty($_POST['movil']) && isset($_POST['adultos']) && !empty($_POST['adultos']) && isset($_POST['infantiles']) && !empty($_POST['infantiles']) && isset($_POST['fechareserva']) && !empty($_POST['fechareserva']) && isset($_POST['horareserva']) && !empty($_POST['horareserva']) && isset($_POST['alergias']) && !empty($_POST['alergias'])) {

    // Conversión de entidades HTML

    $nombre = htmlentities($_POST['nombre']);
     $apellidos= htmlentities($_POST['apellidos']);
     $email= htmlentities($_POST['email']);
     $direccion= htmlentities($_POST['direccion']);
     $poblacion= htmlentities($_POST['poblacion']);
     $provincia= htmlentities($_POST['provincia']);
     $cp= htmlentities($_POST['cp']);
     $movil= htmlentities($_POST['movil']);
     $adultos= htmlentities($_POST['adultos']);
     $infantiles= htmlentities($_POST['infantiles']);
     $fechareserva= htmlentities($_POST['fechareserva']);
     $horareserva= htmlentities($_POST['horareserva']);
     $alergias= htmlentities($_POST['alergias']);

    // Escape de caracteres especiales

    $nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $nombre);
     $apellidos= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $apellidos);
     $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email);
     $direccion= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $direccion);
     $poblacion= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $poblacion);
     $provincia= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $provincia);
     $cp= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $cp);
     $movil= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $movil);
     $adultos= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $adultos);
     $infantiles= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $infantiles);
     $fechareserva= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $fechareserva);
     $horareserva= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $horareserva);
     $alergias= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $alergias);


    // Comprobación de si ya existe una reserva con ese nombre

    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE nombre='$nombre' & apellidos='$_apellidos'");

    if ($result) {

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            echo '<script> alert("La reserva ya existe.");</script>';

        } else {

            $insert = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO reservas (nombre, apellidos, email, direccion, poblacion, provincia, cp, movil, adultos, infantiles, fechareserva, horareserva, alergias, freg) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellidos','$email','$direccion','$poblacion','$provincia','$cp','$movil','$adultos','$infantiles','$fechareserva','$horareserva','$alergias',NOW())");

            if ($insert) {

                echo '<script> alert("La reserva se ha registrado correctamente.");
                location.href="../restaurante/a.php";</script>';

            } else {

                echo '<script> alert("Ha ocurrido un error mientras se guardaba la reserva.");
                location.href="../restaurante/a.php";</script>';

            }

        }

    } else {

        echo '<script> alert("Ha ocurrido un error mientras se obtenían las reservas.");
                location.href="../restaurante/a.php";</script>';

    }

} else {

    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado el nombre.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado los apellidos.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado el email.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado la direccion.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado la poblacion.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado la provincia.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado el codigo postal.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado el movil.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado los adultos.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado los niños.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado la fecha reserva.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado la hora reserva.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado las alergias.");</script>';


}
?>

el que debe mandar los datos a la base de datos.-

<?php

// En primer lugar obtenemos la conexión y la guardamos en $link

$link=new mysqli('javiersaceda.es','javiers1_javiersaceda','zafiros1960');
echo "entramos";
//Seleccionar la base de datos
$db=mysqli_select_db($link,"javiers1_proyecto");
 

if (isset($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['apellidos']) && !empty($_POST['apellidos']) && isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['direccion']) && !empty($_POST['direccion']) && isset($_POST['poblacion']) && !empty($_POST['poblacion']) && isset($_POST['provincia']) && !empty($_POST['provincia']) && isset($_POST['cp']) && !empty($_POST['cp']) && isset($_POST['movil']) && !empty($_POST['movil']) && isset($_POST['adultos']) && !empty($_POST['adultos']) && isset($_POST['infantiles']) && !empty($_POST['infantiles']) && isset($_POST['fechareserva']) && !empty($_POST['fechareserva']) && isset($_POST['horareserva']) && !empty($_POST['horareserva']) && isset($_POST['alergias']) && !empty($_POST['alergias'])) {

    // Conversión de entidades HTML

    $nombre = htmlentities($_POST['nombre']);
     $apellidos= htmlentities($_POST['apellidos']);
     $email= htmlentities($_POST['email']);
     $direccion= htmlentities($_POST['direccion']);
     $poblacion= htmlentities($_POST['poblacion']);
     $provincia= htmlentities($_POST['provincia']);
     $cp= htmlentities($_POST['cp']);
     $movil= htmlentities($_POST['movil']);
     $adultos= htmlentities($_POST['adultos']);
     $infantiles= htmlentities($_POST['infantiles']);
     $fechareserva= htmlentities($_POST['fechareserva']);
     $horareserva= htmlentities($_POST['horareserva']);
     $alergias= htmlentities($_POST['alergias']);

    // Escape de caracteres especiales

    $nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $nombre);
     $apellidos= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $apellidos);
     $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email);
     $direccion= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $direccion);
     $poblacion= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $poblacion);
     $provincia= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $provincia);
     $cp= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $cp);
     $movil= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $movil);
     $adultos= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $adultos);
     $infantiles= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $infantiles);
     $fechareserva= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $fechareserva);
     $horareserva= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $horareserva);
     $alergias= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $alergias);


    // Comprobación de si ya existe una reserva con ese nombre

    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE nombre='$nombre' & apellidos='$_apellidos'");

    if ($result) {

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            echo '<script> alert("La reserva ya existe.");</script>';

        } else {

            $insert = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO reservas (nombre, apellidos, email, direccion, poblacion, provincia, cp, movil, adultos, infantiles, fechareserva, horareserva, alergias, freg) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellidos','$email','$direccion','$poblacion','$provincia','$cp','$movil','$adultos','$infantiles','$fechareserva','$horareserva','$alergias',NOW())");

            if ($insert) {

                echo '<script> alert("La reserva se ha registrado correctamente.");
                location.href="../restaurante/a.php";</script>';

            } else {

                echo '<script> alert("Ha ocurrido un error mientras se guardaba la reserva.");
                location.href="../restaurante/a.php";</script>';

            }

        }

    } else {

        echo '<script> alert("Ha ocurrido un error mientras se obtenían las reservas.");
                location.href="../restaurante/a.php";</script>';

    }

} else {

    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado el nombre.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado los apellidos.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado el email.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado la direccion.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado la poblacion.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado la provincia.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado el codigo postal.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado el movil.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado los adultos.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado los niños.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado la fecha reserva.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado la hora reserva.");</script>';
    echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado las alergias.");</script>';


}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Empezando, hay errores tipográficos.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * ... & apellidos='$_apellidos'");
```

la variable `$_apellidos` no existe, debe ser `$apellidos`. También estas usando `&` como operador de comparación, debes usar `AND`.

Por otro lado, yo eliminaría de plano la línea `db=mysqli_select_db($link, "javiers1_proyecto");` . Según la [documentación de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.select-db.php), esa instrucción solo tiene sentido si estas manejando múltiples BD y quieres cambiar de una a otra. La base de datos *default* se puede seleccionar en la conexión:

```
$link=new mysqli('javiersaceda.es','javiers1_javiersaceda','zafiros1960', 'javiers1_proyecto');
```

Lo siguiente es que `empty()` devuelve `true` si una variable no existe |o| si tiene un valor considerado empty (`false`, `0`, `''`, `array()`), por lo que no es necesario usar `isset()` si ya vas a usar `empty()`. [Leer sobre empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-parameters).

Y finalmente estás escribiendo demasiado código redundante que se puede reducir con funciones. Este tipo de casos es un excelente candidato para aplicar **clases y POO**. Pero en su defecto trabajaremos solo con una función. Puse la conexión `$link` como variable global para no tener que pasarla a la función.

En el `foreach()` se pregunta y procesa en la función cada elemento de la lista `$dbcols`, que corresponden a los campos "`name`" de los input en el html y retorna el valor filtrado. Ese valor va siendo concatenado en la variable `$subquery`. Si un campo está vacío, se retorna `false`, lo que romperá el `for` (`break`) y se imprimirá con **js** que ese campo no ha sido llenado.

Si no hay ningún valor vacío, entonces se arma una consulta, `$query` con el array de `$dbcols` convertido a string y la subconsulta acumulativa `$subquery`.

```
<?php

$link = new mysqli('javiersaceda.es','javiers1_javiersaceda','zafiros1960', 'javiers1_proyecto');
echo "entramos";

function check_input($col) {
    if(empty($_POST[$col])) {
        return false;
    }
    global $link;
    $var = htmlentities($_POST[$col]);
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $var);
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM reservas 
WHERE nombre='".$_POST['nombre']."' and apellidos='".$_POST['apellidos']."' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    $dbcols = array('nombre', 'apellidos', 'email', 'direccion', 'poblacion', 'provincia',
    'cp', 'movil', 'adultos', 'infantiles', 'fechareserva', 'horareserva', 'alergias');

    $empty_field = false;
    $subquery = '';
    foreach($dbcols as $col) {
        $input = check_input($col);
        if($input) {
            $subquery .= ($subquery != '') ? ", "."'$input'" : "'$input'";
        } else {
            $empty_field = true;
            echo '<script> alert("No has ingresado el campo '.$col.'.");
            location.href="../restaurante/a.php";</script>';
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$empty_field) {
        $columns = implode(', ', $dbcols);
        $query = "INSERT INTO reservas ($columns, freg) VALUES ($subquery, NOW())";
        if(mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
            echo '<script> alert("La reserva se ha registrado correctamente.");
                    location.href="../restaurante/a.php";</script>';
        } else {
            '<script> alert("Ha ocurrido un error mientras se guardaba la reserva.");
                    location.href="../restaurante/a.php";</script>';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo '<script> alert("La reserva ya existe.");
    location.href="../restaurante/a.php";</script>';
}
```